# curl - how to submit to paypal javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, curl, paypal

how to submit to `paypal javascript sdk` using curl

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=1234" data-client-token="4321">
```

client-id is query parameter but how about  data-client-token? it is not query and post not support

below did not work

```
#curl https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=1234
#curl -d "data-client-token=4321" https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=1234
#curl -H "data-client-token=4321" https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=1234
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to submit to paypal javascript sdk using curl

You don't, not ever. The JavaScript SDK should always be loaded directly by a **web browser** at runtime. [See here for a basic demo.](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client)

---

If you want to use curl or another backend/server-side tool, instead use the v2/checkout/orders API, [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/)

The best front-end approval flow to pair with the above server-side routes ('Create an Order' and 'Capture Order') will still make use of the JavaScript SDK from a browser: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server